# Pandas strange equality behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

when I'm running the below code snippet -

```
staging_path = 'aws s3 staging path/filename.parquet'
prod_path = 'aws s3 prodpath/filename.parquet'

staging_df = pd.read_parquet(staging_path)
prod_df = pd.read_parquet(prod_path)

print('staging and prod dataframe shape ',staging_df.shape,prod_df.shape)
print('is staging df equals prod df? ',staging_df.equals(prod_df))
df_all = pd.concat([staging_df,prod_df])
df_all.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)
print('leftover rows after dropping duplicates ',df_all.shape)

print('---------sorting and resetting the index----------------------')

staging_df.sort_values(by=['patientid','onsetdate'], inplace = True)
staging_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
prod_df.sort_values(by=['patientid','onsetdate'], inplace = True)
prod_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
print('is staging df equals prod df after sorting? ',staging_df.equals(prod_df))
```

the output I'm getting is -

```
staging and prod dataframe shape  (1626, 7) (1626, 7)
is staging df equals prod df?  False
leftover rows after dropping duplicates  (0, 7)
---------sorting and reseting the index----------------------
is staging df equals prod df after sorting?  False
```

It is strange for me that when there are no unique rows in both dataframe why did the last print gave me FALSE.

both prod_df and staging_df looks like -

```
patientid   onsetdate   facilityid  diagnosiscode   diagnosisdesc   classification  rank
48119       2017-03-08  1           M65             M               During Stay     A
48239       2017-03-23  1           E86             M               During Stay     B
48569       2017-03-24  1           E89             D               During DX#6     C
```

both dataframes info looks like -

```
patientid         1626 non-null int64
onsetdate         1626 non-null datetime64[ns]
facilityid        1626 non-null int64
diagnosiscode     1626 non-null object
diagnosisdesc     1626 non-null object
classification    1453 non-null object
rank              1626 non-null object
```

Comment: I would suggest reading through the [pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) instead, as it provides way more control and flexibility at testing...

Comment: I'm using pandas .25 version , don't want to change the version. asser_frame_equal is available in 1.0

Comment: I read a link where it said df.equals yields an incorrect result mostly when comparing floats since python does this weird approximation thingy for floating-point columns, but yours doesn't have a float column

Comment: I would also try to `sort_values` by all columns, rather than just the first two, to see if that helps align the rows better in both dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at what exactly the differences between the two DataFrames are to understand why they are not equal.

To compare two DataFrames that have the same shape, index, and column names, you can use `df1 != df2` to create a DataFrame of Boolean values indicating where the differences are. You can then use that Boolean DataFrame as a mask on the original DataFrames to show only those values that are different. Here's an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'patientid': [48119, 48239, 48569],
                    'onsetdate': ['2017-03-08', '2017-03-23', '2017-03-24'],
                    'diagnosiscode': ['M65', 'E86', 'E89']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'patientid': [48219, 48239, 48569],
                    'onsetdate': ['2017-03-08', '2017-03-20', '2017-03-24'],
                    'diagnosiscode': ['M65', 'E86', 'M89']})

df1 != df2
```

```
    patientid   onsetdate   diagnosiscode
0   True        False       False
1   False       True        False
2   False       False       True
```

```py
df1[df1 != df2]
```

```
    patientid   onsetdate   diagnosiscode
0   48119.0     NaN         NaN
1   NaN         2017-03-23  NaN
2   NaN         NaN         E89
```

```py
df2[df1 != df2]
```

```
    patientid   onsetdate   diagnosiscode
0   48219.0     NaN         NaN
1   NaN         2017-03-20  NaN
2   NaN         NaN         M89
```

I haven't tested this with pandas 0.25, but it's pretty basic, so I would expect it to work.